# Related posts wordpress loop excluding certain tags

Tags: wordpress, loops, tags

Is there a way to exclude certain tags from a related posts loop, while it still finding the other tags? Here is the code I have but I'm aware there's no such value as tag_slug__not_in, but I don't want to use ID's because they're messy, is there no way to exclude tags via slug, and generally will this work because I am saying all tags included are any? Any help is massively appreciated!

```
<?php  //for use in the loop, list 5 post titles related to first tag on current post
$backup = $post;  // backup the current object
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
$tagIDs = array();
if ($tags) {
$tagcount = count($tags);
for ($i = 0; $i < $tagcount; $i++) {
  $tagIDs[$i] = $tags[$i]->term_id;
}
$args=array(
  'tag__in' => $tagIDs,
  'tag_slug__not_in' => array('investing', 'investment', 'travel', 'shopping', 'retail',       'organisations', 'governments', 'government', 'individuals', 'entrepeneurs', 'companies', 'markets', 'finance', 'clean-tech', 'money', 'world', 'business'),
  'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
  'showposts'=>5,
  'caller_get_posts'=>1,
  'post_type' => array('post','indepth','feature','interview')
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
<h3>Related Articles</h3>
<?php  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <ul><li><p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p></li>
    </ul>
  <?php endwhile;
} else { ?>

<?php }
}
$post = $backup;  // copy it back
wp_reset_query(); // to use the original query again
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree, it's pretty silly that they don't have a tag_slug__not_in parameter.

In any event, I think you can use the `tax_query` parameter for WP_Query to achieve what you're looking to do. The following code is untested:

```
$args=array(
  'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
  'showposts'=>5,
  'caller_get_posts'=>1,
  'post_type' => array('post','indepth','feature','interview'),
  'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $tagIDs
    ),

    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array('investing', 'investment', 'travel', 'shopping', 'retail', 'organisations', 'governments', 'government', 'individuals', 'entrepeneurs', 'companies', 'markets', 'finance', 'clean-tech', 'money', 'world', 'business'),
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    )
  )
);
```

If this doesn't work, you may want to try to read up more on the [Taxonomy Parameters in WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and see if adding a `relation` key in the `tax_query` array can further aid in the solution of your problem.

Comment: Brilliant, that works to an extent, but what it essentially does, is more or less disassociates everything.. what I'm trying to do is get it to ignore those tags, but pay attention to other tags within the posts that are tagged with that. I'm not sure if this is actually possible though to be honest, as obvisously it's saying do not display posts with this tag in, when I mean more, do not display posts if they have only this tag in common with you. Does this make sense?

Comment: I basically want it to ignore those tags, but not the posts so that it still searches for other related tags within those posts. Trickkky one. Mmm I'm not sure it's possible now I'm thinking about it.

Comment: Check my updated answer. I'm thinking that might be what you're looking to do.

Comment: I think that makes the NOT IN not work as it just relates to all of the tags again mm this is tricky :(

Comment: Can amend your post and give an example of what you expect to happen given certain posts and tags?